# Загрузка удалённой картинки с RewriteRule

Tags: php

В общем ситуация такая. Есть система, данные о картинке хранятся в базе в формате

> 'images/abcd.jpg'
>
> 'images/something/abcd.jpg'

На сервере в папке images лежит .htaccess который в зависимости от множества условий rewrite на другие сервера где лежат оригиналы этих картинок.

Моя задача получить параметры изображения, и в дальнейшем возможно придётся обработать их(создать thumbs, итд). Но так как они удалённые, их нужно обработать.

Сложность также заключается в том, что  и адрес текущего сервера также подвергся модификации. И код рассклонирован на несколько серверов. Где SUBDOMAIN и PROJECT тоже меняются и формируются в корневом .htaccess в зависимости от параметров окружения сервера.

> http://**SUBDOMAIN**.test.com/**PROJECT**/images/abcd.jpg

Если вставить значение из базы в `<img src='images/abcd.jpg'>` оно адекватно отобразится. Но как такое изображение обработать на php?

Понятное дело что скорей всего нужно будет скачать его через curl или file_get_contents для получения getimagesize и создания thumb. Но нужно сформировать полный URL учитываю правила и работу .htaccess

Comment: А почему бы не заворачивать все правила (те, что последние в цепочке перенаправлений) в .htaccess для картинок на php-обработчик, передавая в виде параметров в него же необходимые данные?

Comment: Больная тема. Я тоже не люблю .htaccess. Представим что в данной ситуации нельзя решить задачу таким образом.

Comment: Вообще-то, запросы через `file_get_contents`, как и через `curl`, тоже подвергаются обработке на стороне сервера, а значит и правила в вашем .htaccess на них действуют. Я не понимаю, в чем проблема?

Comment: Как сформировать полный путь, который можно будет скормить `curl` или `file_get_contents` из частичного, который хранится в базе. Без дублирования логики формирования адреса из .htaccess в php?

Answer (score 1):

Запросы через `file_get_contents`, как и через `curl`, тоже подвергаются обработке на стороне сервера, а значит и правила в вашем .htaccess на них действуют.

Полный URL у вас `http://site.com/images/abcd.jpg`, судя по адресу в картинке.

Значит в PHP можно сформировать его как-то так:

```
$scheme = 'http';
// Для Apache
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') {
    $scheme = 'https';
}

file_get_contents($scheme . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/images/abcd.jpg');
```

Картинку по этому запросу вы получите.

---

#### Обновление

Можно заворачивать все картинки на PHP обработчик (добавьте последним правилом):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpe?g|png|gif)$
RewriteRule (.*) /image.php?path=/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Тогда запрос вида:
`http://site.com/images/abcd.jpg?width=40`
преобразуется в такой:
`http://site.com/image.php?path=/images/abcd.jpg&width=40`

А дальше уже дело техники.

Comment: `http://SUBDOMAIN.test.com/images/abcd.jpg`

Тут выпадает **PROJECT** который формируется в .htaccess, можно продублировать логику и на PHP получить его. Но мне бы этого не хотелось.

Comment: @Ninazu, зачем дублировать логику? У вас .htaccess сам отдаст картинку по запросу `http://subdomain.site.com/images/abcd.jpg` отсюда `http://subdomain.site.com/projects/images/abcd.jpg`. Вы же в вопросе явно указали, что картинка вида `<img src='/images/abcd.jpg'>` адекватно отображается.

Comment: Сорри. Мой косяк. Обновил вопрос. Там без слеша ведущего.

Comment: @Ninazu, я обновил ответ